# Постоянное перенаправление в joomla 2.5

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, redirect

Недавно появилось проблема с постоянным редиректом главной страницы в joomla 2.5
Есть еще одна особенность, что в админпанель с логин паролем не заходит а тупа как будто обновляет страницу.
Проблема появилось сама по себе, никто не трогал настройки сайта.
Хостеры говорят с нашей стороны все ок, вы там разберитесь с htaccess и настройками joomla.
Что посоветуете? кто-нибудь сталикивался с подобной ситуацией?
Ксатит сам сайт tajikcoop.tj

Comment: Вас взломали, ну или хотя бы покажите ваш .htaccess полностью, а то кроме `303 See other` в браузере ни чего не видно :Р